# Why is the Git Diff/Patch info different than the Github representation of that patch?

Tags: ruby, git, github, diff

When you look at a diff of a file, it will show you the diff info at the top, and then it highlights the changes below.

However, in every example I have looked at...the line number that Github highlights with the change, is always different than the line number that Git specified in the Diff/Patch info.

For example [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/31651bff4cd1fa9b05d6d80ec483d8633183f12f) (note the diff data says `@@ -362,7 +362,7 @@ def association_instance_set(name, association`, yet Github begins the highlighting at line 365.)

[image: Github-Diff-Highlight-1]

Or this one:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Or finally this one:

[image]

It seems as if the actual line-number highlighted by Github is usually around 3 lines higher than the patch/diff data from Git specified.

When I check their API, pull down the first file I highlighted and linked above, spit it out into an array and then do a line count in the array using `index`, I get a different result too.

The line where the diff specifies the change is made i.e. `362`, comes out using my array conversion method to `364` and not `365` as Github highlighted it.

So something is a bit off.

Why is that?

Comment: Which language are you using to count with ```index```? Does it use zero-based indices (i.e. line 365 has index 364)?

Comment: Good point Owen. I am using Ruby, and it does user Zero-based indices. So that would account for the `364` to `365` disparity between my implementation and Github's. However, that still doesn't account for the `+3` disparity between GH and Git.

Comment: `git diff` has an option `-U<n>` or `--unified=<n>` to define the lines of context. The default n is 3.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're really looking for here.  Some possible questions are: "why supply any context at all with a diff", "why when supplying context is it 3 lines to either side of a changed line", "why are diffs line-oriented in the first place", "how does one highlight the *actual* change *within* a diff that supplies unchanged context", and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with those patches, they look all exactly how they should look.

Unified diff includes 3 lines for *context* (per default, this can usually be changed by the diff provider, in case of `git diff`  this is `-U<n>` or `--unified=<n>`).

Lets look at the *hunk* in your first example:

`@@ -362,7 +362,7 @@`

It says that the *patch file* starts at line 362, and that 7 lines are included in the diff. If we look at the diff, we can see that it indeed starts at line 362 and is 7 lines long.

If we look at the diff in more detail, we see that line 362, 363, 364 are produced *verbatim*. Line 365 is labeled with a `-` (respective `+`) because it got removed and another line re-inserted. This is highlighted by the red/green color in the output. One thing that is *not* in the actual diff file is GitHubs highlighting of exactly which parts of the line was changed. Thats a custom enhancement of GitHub.

And after that, the three next context lines which are not changed are displayed verbatim.

Unified diff simply provides context lines and includes them in the diff, and GitHub shows it this way, too.

You have 1 changed line (365), and three lines before and after for context. makes 7 lines in total that are included in the patch/diff file (starting at 362).

Comment: Ohhh....ok...this makes much more sense to me. So, if there were 2 lines that were changed, that would prolly look like this: `@@ -362,8 + 362,8 @@`?

Comment: @marcamillion Yes.

Answer (score 2):

It's "off by three" because the diff format includes three lines before the line that actually has the change.

So `@@ -362,7 +362,7 @@` means the change took place on line 362 + 3 = 365 but the relevant part of the code starts at line 362.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say here, but why would they just not show the 3 lines before that line? i.e. show from line `359` and include the actual change on line `362` like you would expect and like the diff says?

Comment: @marcamillion: by "they", do you mean Github or the authors of the patch file format? It seems reasonable that Github highlights the relevant lines (and whatever other context) without constraining themselves too much by the diff output. If you're talking about the patch format then there may either be reasons for doing this or it could just be for historical reasons (I'm not sure).

Comment: @marcamillion There is no change in line 362. Unified diff includes 3 lines for context. First change is at 365.

Comment: @Polygnome That's exactly my point. The actual patch data from git i.e. `@@ -362,7 +362,7 @@ def association_instance_set(name, association)` says that the changes begin at line 362 and happen over 7 lines (for both addition and subtraction).

Comment: @SimeonVisser yeh I meant Github. In other words, I guess what I am wondering is....they have two ways to show context. They can either change the line highlighted and shown where the change occurs in the UI (i.e. rather than highlighting line `362` they highlight `365` -- which is what they did), OR they adjust the viewport to show from line `359` and keep the line change at `362` which the git patch data specified. It seems like the latter would make more sense, but they did the former instead. So I am just wondering what would lead them to make that decision.

Comment: @SimeonVisser However It seems like that's standard with most unified diff tools? To just push the lines up/down to show the change rather than moving the viewport to show the changes?

Comment: @marcamillion You simply seem to be misinterpreting what the line number in `@@ -362,7 +362,7 @@` says. It does not mean that the change is on line 362. It means that **the portion of the code shown in the patch starts from line 362**. And that portion includes unchanged contexts, as others have pointed out.

Comment: @marcamillion: my guess would be that the actual line numbers that changed are easier to understand. Many developers get their work done without ever looking at diff/patch files but they rely on GUI tools. In that sense Github designed their product around files and lines that changed rather than the underlying tool's output.

Comment: @SimeonVisser No. The actual diff file includes exactly the same, its produced there correctly. Its not something GitHub does, but the fundamental principle of unified diffs.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub (and unified diff tools in general) provide some context around the change - three lines above and below, where available. The numbers printed with the output include the context lines. So, for example, given a file consisting of the numbers 1 to 100 (one per line) when diff'ed against a file without the number 42, the context shows 7 lines starting at line 39 (or 6 lines after the deletion) even though the only line changed is line 42.

```
$ diff -u 100 99
--- 100 2016-07-31 09:31:25.000000000 -0400
+++ 99  2016-07-31 09:31:34.000000000 -0400
@@ -39,7 +39,6 @@
 39
 40
 41
-42
 43
 44
 45
```